# Splitting string with delimiter one and index[0] with other

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

How do I split this multple delimiter without creating two list and appending which seems to be very performance suffering opernation.

```
string = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV'

string.split("|")[0].split(".") + string.split("|")[1:]
Out[156]: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV']
```

**Simple `re.split(r'[.|]')`** doesnt work because of in second part of string.

```
string = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|D|F.g|.Y|'

re.split(r'[./|]', string)
Out[179]: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'D', 'F', 'g', '', 'Y', '']
```

Data `NOPQ` and `RSTUV` may contain `.` but it is not delimiter. Number for pipe delimited columns may increase. But, always until first `|`, delimiter `.` is seperater after first `|` only `|` is delimiter.

Few other possible combination that data could be,

```
string = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|DFGR'
string.split("|")[0].split(".") + string.split("|")[1:]
Out[174]: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'DFGR']

string = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|D.F.GR.'
string.split("|")[0].split(".") + string.split("|")[1:]
Out[176]: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'D.F.GR.']

string = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|D|F.g|.Y|'
string.split("|")[0].split(".") + string.split("|")[1:]
Out[178]: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'D', 'F.g', '.Y', '']

    string = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|D|F.g|Y|H|J|K|R|Y' 
string.split("|")[0].split(".") + string.split("|")[1:]
Out[181]: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'D', 'F.g', 
'Y', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'R', 'Y']
```

Comment: Try [this demo](http://ideone.com/WT7mOx) - no idea if reversing the string and using a normal `re` module speeds things up, but is another alternative to `regex` module.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks I tried that even this is slow. I am actually parsing log with 20 M records per day. And this is just toy data actually there are 35 to 62 column splits

Comment: I see. It is a great pity Python `re` does not support `\G`.

Comment: @stribizhev: I just realize there's no need to the `\G` anchor...oops.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I know it can be done with a variable-width look-behind. Again, something I miss anywhere but .NET (ok, not speaking about the constrained-width lookbehind with ICU-based regex engines).

Comment: If you don't need empty matches also try `re.findall(r'(?<=\|)[^|]+|[^.|]+', s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new answer:

With the re module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ABCD..EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|D|F.g|Y|H|J|K|R|Y||'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\|)[^|]*|(?:(?<=\.)|\A)[^|.]*', s)
['ABCD', '', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'D', 'F.g', 'Y', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'R', 'Y', '', '']
```

Old answer:

With the [new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can do that:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'ABCD.EFGH.IJKLM|NOPQ|RSTUV|D|F.g|Y|H|J|K|R|Y'
>>> regex.findall(r'\G\.?\K[^.|]+|[^|]+', s)
['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKLM', 'NOPQ', 'RSTUV', 'D', 'F.g', 'Y', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'R', 'Y']
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC8uS1/1)

Where `\G` matches the beginning of the string or the next position after the previous match and `\K` discards all characters on the left (the optional dot here) from the match result.

`\G` is used to force all results to be contiguous until the first pipe. Since nothing matches the pipe in the pattern, the contiguity is broken and the second branch `[^|]+` is used for other items.

Note: in the same way you can choose to ensure the contiguity in the second part of the string with this pattern: `\|\K[^|]+|[^|.]+` *(that can be interesting if the second part of the string contains a lot of items)*. But this time no need to use the `\G` anchor since each contiguous items are preceded by a pipe.

Note2: if you want to take in account empty items, you can change the pattern to:

```
regex.findall(r'\G(?:\A|\.)\K[^.|]*|[^|]+|(?<=\|)', s)
```

or

```
regex.findall(r'\|\K[^|]*|(?:\.|\A)\K[^|.]*', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module. Using `re.split` should do the trick, e.g. `re.split('[|.]', string)`